# ¿Yugoslavia o Yugoeslavia? ¿Con qué frecuencia se ha usado una "e" antes de "s" seguida de consonante?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, nombres-propios, letras, transliteración

Yugoslavia fue un país fundado en 1918 y deshecho a finales del siglo XX. Su nombre viene de *yugo* y *slavia* (*eslavos del sur*) y ese sufijo de *slavia* me resulta interesante. ¿Por qué? Pues porque es típico que los hispanohablantes pronunciemos *es* en lugar de *s* cuando esta letra aparece seguida de otra consonante. Así, en clases de ruso te corrigen el [*spasibo*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE) de *gracias* cuando pronuncias */espasibo/* o en clases de inglés te dicen que vale, que muy bien que hables *espanish*, pero la *e* inicial no se dice.

Saco todo este tema porque parece que la *e* antes de *slavia* se usó en ciertos momentos de la historia. Por ejemplo, en [un tuit](https://mobile.twitter.com/alain_acevedo/status/1300691742707134464) me encontré con esta imagen del mapa de Europa sacado en la edición del periódico español La Vanguardia el 2 de septiembre de 1939 (tras la invasión de Polonia por parte de Alemania):

> [image]

Como veis, en lugar del *Yugoslavia* clásico aparece *Yugoeslavia*. El DPD tiene un artículo al respecto que dice que ambos son válidos:

> [**Yugoslavia**](https://www.rae.es/dpd/Yugoslavia). El nombre de esta antigua nación de Europa tiene dos formas igualmente válidas, Yugoslavia y Yugoeslavia. Es preferible la primera, tanto por su mayor frecuencia de uso como por su más sencilla articulación. Lo mismo cabe decir de las formas respectivas del gentilicio: yugoslavo (preferible) y yugoeslavo.

Sin embargo, Ngram de Google [nos muestra](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yugoslavia%2Cyugoeslavia&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3) cómo poco a poco esta grafía ha ido cayendo, no solo porque el país no existe sino porque la variante sin la *e* copa casi todos los usos:

> [image]

Esta desproporción en el uso reciente también la veo consultando el [Corpus del Nuevo Diccionario Histórico del Español](http://web.frl.es/CNDHE/org/publico/pages/consulta/entradaCompleja.view), con una relación de 1 a 8 en favor de la variante *Yugoslavia*.

Hasta aquí los hechos. La duda que me surge es más general, sobre cuán típico ha sido el uso de una *e* antecediendo la *s* seguida de consonante a la hora de importar términos extranjeros recientes (los latinismos quedarían fuera de la ecuación) y si ha ido en paralelo a algún tipo de evolución de los hablantes, la importación de términos, etc. Por ejemplo, ¿tiene que ver que cada vez conozcamos y hablemos más idiomas?

Comment: Estás buscando palabras que han perdido (o ganado) la *e* antes de la *s*? O préstamos del extranjero? Porque si no, diría que hay muchísimas (demasiadas) palabras de los dos tipos (*estado, estilo, esperar, esclavo, prestar, fiesta* / *ortostático, asteroide, astigmatismo, casta, pasta, pista*...). No creo que te refieras a todas esas palabras, pero no me queda claro a cuáles te refieres.

Comment: @wimi me referiría especialmente a palabras extranjeras importadas _recientemente_, es decir, en el español moderno. Gracias por el apunte, edité la pregunta para clarificar un poco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El fenómeno de Yugoslavia, se presentó también con otros eslavos, me refiero a los de la que alguna vez fuera la República Checa y Eslava, que también se llamó Checoslovaquia, pero que en Español también se decía Checoeslovaquia. El artículo del DPD dice algo semejante al de su prima Yusgoslavia.

> **Checoslovaquia.** El nombre de esta antigua nación europea tiene dos
> formas válidas, Checoslovaquia y Checoeslovaquia; pero es mayoritaria
> y preferible la primera. Lo mismo cabe decir de su gentilicio:
> checoslovaco es preferible a checoeslovaco.

Y tampoco debe sorprendernos que Ngram de Google, [nos muestre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=checoslovaquia%2C%20checoeslovaquia&share=&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3) una tendencia semejante.

[image]

En ambos casos el término con el hiato fue cayendo en desuso, pero mucho antes del auge de fenómenos como el que cada vez conozcamos más idiomas. Otra posibilidad es que, aun en español, es más fácil pronunciar Yugoslavia que Yugoeslavia.

Answer (score 6):

En el DLE se recogen actualmente los siguientes casos de palabras (no provenientes del latín) importadas de idiomas extranjeros:

- *[**scooter**](https://dle.rae.es/scooter)*, que redirige a *[escúter](https://dle.rae.es/esc%C3%BAter)*.
- ***[sketch](https://dle.rae.es/sketch)***, voz inglesa sin transcripción propuesta.
- ***[slip](https://dle.rae.es/slip)***, voz inglesa, el DPD propone *[eslip](https://www.rae.es/dpd/eslip)*, pero esta no está recogida por el DLE.
- ***[spa](https://dle.rae.es/spa)***, voz inglesa, a su vez proveniente de la ciudad de Spa, en Bélgica; sin transcripción propuesta.
- ***spam***, voz inglesa sin transcripción propuesta, aunque se propone usar *[correo basura](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AyfHjz9#Sc9DCpf)*.
- ***[spanglish](https://dle.rae.es/spanglish)***, que redirige a *[espanglish](https://dle.rae.es/espanglish)*.
- ***[sparring](https://dle.rae.es/sparring)***, voz inglesa, el DPD propone *[esparrin](https://www.rae.es/dpd/esparrin)*, no recogida por el DLE.
- ***[split](https://dle.rae.es/split)***, solamente usada en el nombre del postre *[banana split](https://dle.rae.es/banana#GgvHkzH)*, sin adaptación propuesta.
- ***[sponsor](https://dle.rae.es/sponsor)***, curiosamente [el DPD la da por incorrecta](https://www.rae.es/dpd/sponsor), proponiendo *[patrocinador](https://dle.rae.es/patrocinador)*.
- ***[sport](https://dle.rae.es/sport)***, no tiene adaptación propuesta, pero el DPD la considera un [anglicismo evitable](https://www.rae.es/dpd/sport) en favor de *informal* (en el caso de *ropa de sport*).
- ***[spot](https://dle.rae.es/spot)***, otro anglicismo evitable sin adaptación propuesta, el DPD [recomienda usar](https://www.rae.es/dpd/spot) *anuncio*, *cuña* o *comercial* en su primera acepción, y *foco*, *reflector* o *cañón de luz* en su segunda.
- ***[spray](https://dle.rae.es/spray)***, que redirige a *[espray](https://dle.rae.es/espray)*, y este a *[aerosol](https://dle.rae.es/aerosol)*.
- ***[sprint](https://dle.rae.es/sprint)***, que redirige a *[esprint](https://dle.rae.es/esprint)*.
- ***[squash](https://dle.rae.es/squash)***, sin adaptación propuesta.
- ***[stand](https://dle.rae.es/stand)***, que redirige a *[estand](https://dle.rae.es/estand)*. El DPD [recomienda](https://www.rae.es/dpd/stand) usar *pabellón*.
- ***[standing](https://dle.rae.es/standing)***, el DPD [lo califica](https://www.rae.es/dpd/standing) también como evitable en favor de *nivel* o *categoría*.
- ***[stent](https://dle.rae.es/stent)***, sin adaptación propuesta.
- ***[stock](https://dle.rae.es/stock)***, que redirige a *existencias*, sin adaptación propuesta. [Según el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/stock) también puede sustituirse por *reservas*.
- ***[stop](https://dle.rae.es/stop)***, sin adaptación propuesta, y dado que aparece en las señales de tráfico es poco probable que se llegue a adaptar, aunque s[egún el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/stop) hay muchos países que están cambiando las señales de tráfico por *alto* o *pare*.
- ***[striptease](https://dle.rae.es/striptease)***, que redirige a *[estriptis](https://dle.rae.es/estriptis)* (también *estriptís*).

Hasta aquí la lista, nótese que todas las palabras deben escribirse en cursiva dada su condición de extranjerismos crudos. Diría que todas estas palabras son términos que se han ido incorporando al diccionario conforme hemos ido tomando cada vez más contacto con la lengua inglesa. En todo caso, aunque muchas de las palabras no tienen adaptación propuesta, yo reconozco que digo "esquech", "espá", "espónsor", "estop" cuando hablo, no me paro a pensar que tengo que evitar la *e-* del principio.

Resulta curioso, por otra parte, echar un vistazo a las palabras que empiezan por *s* más consonante recogidas en el *Autoridades* del siglo XVIII y ver cómo ninguna de ellas se mantiene hoy tal y como se recogieron entonces. Casos como *sperma* (que ya entonces se decía que equivalía a *[esperma](https://dle.rae.es/esperma)*), *splenico* (hoy *[esplénico](https://dle.rae.es/espl%C3%A9nico)*), *stentoreo* (hoy *[estentóreo](https://dle.rae.es/estent%C3%B3reo)*), *stereographia* (hoy *[estereografía](https://dle.rae.es/estereograf%C3%ADa)*), *sternon* (hoy *[esternón](https://dle.rae.es/estern%C3%B3n)*), *stoico* (ya por entonces con *e-* inicial también, hoy *[estoico](https://dle.rae.es/estoico)*), y otras. Yo diría que para que una palabra entre en el vocabulario español está claro que debe adoptar la *e-* inicial en caso de comenzar con *s-* más consonante (salvo que sea *sh-* o *sw-*, que son casos aparte), sin que ello tenga que ver con el hecho de saber más o menos idiomas, es simplemente que nosotros pronunciamos así.

Ahora bien, en el caso de que la palabra afectada vaya en medio de una palabra compuesta la cosa cambia, dado que en este caso se antepone la facilidad de pronunciación. Por ejemplo, decimos *[aerostático](https://dle.rae.es/aerost%C3%A1tico)* y no *aeroestático*.

Answer (score 2):

Such words appear to come from two pathways:

1. A direct loan, and since the prefix ends in a vowel there is no need for a prosthetic /e-/ before the /sC/ consonant cluster onset in the root (e.g. Yugoslavia → *yugoslavia*)
2. A calque of the foreign word using extant Spanish prefix / roots, where the root itself already has a prosthetic /e-/ (e.g. Yugoslavia → Yugo + Slavia → *yugo* + *eslavia* → *yugoeslavia*)

Other examples are "autostop" vs "auto**e**stop", or "arteriosclerosis" vs "arterio**e**sclerosis". Since both are phonetically valid in Spanish (due to the prefix), either may win out as most popular, but with time /oe/ may (depending on stress) simplify to /we/ or /o/.